# Getting MAX() from two tables in Django -- equivalent to using SQL UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models

Suppose I have two tables that both have a `created_datetime` field.  How can I get the `MAX(created_datetime)`, with both of them taken into account.  In SQL this is done with a  `UNION`

I would prefer to use Django models to do this, but if need be I can do this with raw SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
max(Model1.objects.aggregate(max_date = Max('created_datetime'))['max_date'], Model2.objects.aggregate(max_date = Max('created_datetime'))['max_date'])
```

This doesn't do a `UNION`, but you get what you require.

**N.B.** : `max` is a python function and `Max` a django models function (
`from django.db.models.aggregates import Max` has to be used for `Max`).

You can also do something like the following:

```
max(Model1.objects.all().values_list('created_datetime',flat=True).extend(Model2.objects.all().values_list('created_datetime',flat=True)))
```

Here, aggregation hasn't been used (and so, the `Max` not used). `max` of python has still been used and anything like UNION of sql is still not seen, but, joining of 2 lists has been used.

You can see what suits you bests or some other 3rd solution if any drops by. I would really love to even know a better solution than the above. :)

You could also refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313137/using-django-how-can-i-combine-two-queries-from-separate-models-into-one-query) to see if it helps you.

Comment: I'm using your suggestion for the time being, but will leave the question open.  One thing for people to beware of with your answer is to validate that both querysets are not empty, otherwise you'll get an error: `can't compare datetime.datetime to NoneType`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard without any other information, but I think you want [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest).

`MAX` operates along rows (ie it turns many rows into one row), and `GREATEST` operates along columns (turns many columns into one column).

If you want the *single* biggest `created_datetime` out of both tables, you'd do:

```
SELECT GREATEST( MAX(t1.created_datetime), MAX(t2.created_datetime) )
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON ....
....
```

The `MAX(t1.created_datetime)` grabs the max datetime from t1, the `MAX(t2.created_datetime)` grabs the max from t2, and `GREATEST` gets the larger of these two.

Comment: Oh, I see this is a django question as well as a MySQL question - I don't know anything about django, so perhaps you know how to translate this syntax into django.

Comment: Nope.  That's the motivation for the question.