# Concatenate two QuerySets

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have the following two models:

```
class JobPosition(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name='positions')
    position = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.Position')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()

class ExternalJob(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    position = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.Position') 
    date_added = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

How would I concatenate a Queryset, basically combining the following into one QS?

```
internal_jobs = JobPosition.objects.filter(end_date__gte=datetime.now())
external_jobs = ExternalJob.objects.filter(end_date__gte=datetime.now())
all_jobs = (internal_jobs + external_jobs).order_by('-date_added')
```

Answer (score 1):

First see if this similar question help you: [Using django how can I combine two queries from separate models into one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313137/using-django-how-can-i-combine-two-queries-from-separate-models-into-one-query) . This might be the approach you have to do in order to append another SQL statement (though I am not sure if its possible to do what you are asking on the SQL side)

If all you want to achieve is a lazy evaluating combination of these two queryset's then you can use itertools.chain:

```
from itertools import chain

combined = chain(internal_jobs, external_jobs)
# combined is a generator that will iterate over your combined
# iteratables
for result in combined:
    # do something
```

I think for the final date sort, you might have to do this on the client side. The full queryset list will be evaluated when you do the `sorted` call.

```
from operator import attrgetter

combined = chain(internal_jobs, external_jobs)
for result in sorted(combined, key=attrgetter("date_added"), reverse=True):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

*update*

Just found [How to combine 2 or more querysets in a Django view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view) , refs it for normal case

---

If the performance is critical and the result is used as an iterator, below is a simpler version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/313149/165603 in the link posted by jdi

```
def merge_by_latest_date_added(*querysets):
    querysets = [[qs, None] for qs in querysets]

    def iterator_helper():
        for qs_v in querysets[:]:
            qs, v = qs_v
            if v is not None:
                continue
            try:
                qs_v[1] = qs.next()
            except StopIteration:
                querysets.remove(qs_v)
        return querysets

    while iterator_helper():
        qs_v = max(querysets, key=lambda x:x[1].date_added)
        yield qs_v[1]
        qs_v[1] = None
```

You could then

```
internal_jobs = internal_jobs.order_by('-date_added').iterator()
external_jobs = externals_jobs.order_by('-date_added').iterator()
all_jobs = merge_by_latest_date_added(internal_jobs, external_jobs)
```

For DB backends such as psycopg2, you may want to wrap querysets by [using trick](http://www.mellowmorning.com/2010/03/03/django-query-set-iterator-for-really-large-querysets/) to reduce memory footprint.

You could also isolate code inside the `while` statement to make the merge function a general version. I used it to process large querysets sharing PK in practice, for example.