# Merging querysets from different models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have 2 models in one app and 1 view. I'm currently pulling information from 1 model perfectly fine. However i wish to pull in another model from the same app and output them both to the same page.

The idea of the page is it being a a news hub so it's pulling through different types of news posts (from one model) and a different type of post which is from the other model.

I'm fairly new to Django so go easy! :) Anyway here is the code:

//VIEWS

```
def news_home(request):

    page_context = details(request, path="news-hub", only_context=True)

    recent_posts = NewsPost.objects.filter(live=True, case_study=False).order_by("-posted")[:5]

    recent_posts_pages = Paginator(recent_posts, 100)

    current_page = request.GET.get("page", 1)

    this_page = recent_posts_pages.page(current_page)

    notes = BriefingNote.objects.filter(live=True).order_by("-posted")

    news_categories = NewsCategory.objects.all()




    news_context = {
        "recent_posts": this_page.object_list,
        "news_categories": news_categories,
        "pages": recent_posts_pages,
        "note": notes,


    }

    context = dict(page_context)
    context.update(news_context)


    return render_to_response('news_hub_REDESIGN.html', context,  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

//model 1

```
class BriefingNote(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/briefing_notes', blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/briefing_notes')
    live = models.BooleanField(help_text="The post will only show on the frontend if the 'live' box is checked")
    categories = models.ManyToManyField("NewsCategory")

    # Dates
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.title
```

// model 2

```
class NewsPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    slug = models.SlugField(help_text="This will form the URL of the post")

    summary = models.TextField(help_text="To be used on the listings pages. Any formatting here will be ignored on the listings page.")
    post = models.TextField(blank=True)
    #TO BE REMOVED????
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(help_text="To be displayed on listings pages", upload_to="images/news", blank=True)
    remove_thumbnail = models.BooleanField()
```

I'm outputting the content on the front end like so:

```
{% for post in recent_posts %}





                    <div class='news_first'>

                        <img class="news_thumb" src="/media/{% if post.article_type %}{{post.article_type.image}}{% endif %}{% if post.news_type %}{{post.news_type.image}}{% endif%}" alt="">
                        <h3><a href='{{post.get_absolute_url}}'>{% if post.article_type.title %}{{post.title}}{% endif %} <span>{{post.posted|date:"d/m/y"}}</span></a></h3>
                        <p class='news_summary'>
                            {% if post.thumbnail %}<a href='{{post.get_absolute_url}}'><img src='{% thumbnail post.thumbnail 120x100 crop upscale %}' alt='{{post.title}}' class='news_thumbnail'/></a>{% endif %}{{post.summary|striptags}} <a href='{{post.get_absolute_url}}'>Read full story &raquo;</a>
                        </p>
                        <div class='clearboth'></div>
                    </div>




            {% endfor %}
```

I was thinking perhaps i could output them both within the same forloop however they need to ordered by -posted. So i though this could mess things up.

If you need anymore info please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313137/using-django-how-can-i-combine-two-queries-from-separate-models-into-one-query

Comment: Is this actually what I need to do? As that post they go off topic and it seems like they are doing something different at the end result?

Comment: I don't see a DateTimeField in NewsPost, how do you intend to order them by post date ?

Comment: I've not posted all the model fiels as the model is fairly large.

Comment: That post is unable to help? Can anyone help me out? It's driving me mad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now solved the problem.

```
news_hub = list(chain(notes, recent_posts))

news_hub = sorted(
    chain(notes, recent_posts),
    key = attrgetter('posted'), reverse=True)[:10]
```