# Django: How do I sort on date from two models?

Tags: django, date, sorting, models

1.) I have the following models.py definition:

```
    from django.db import models
    from datetime import date

    class Author(models.Model):
        author  = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return '%s' % (self.author)

    class SystemA(models.Model):
        author      = models.ForeignKey(Author)
        date        = models.DateField()
        system      = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, default="System A")
        description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=6)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s' % (self.date, self.author, self.system, self.description, self.status)

    class SystemB(models.Model):
        author      = models.ForeignKey(Author)
        date        = models.DateField()
        system      = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, default="System B")
        description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=6)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s' % (self.date, self.author, self.system, self.description, self.status)
```

2.) This admin.py definition:

```
    from acc.models import SystemA, SystemB, Author
    from django.contrib import admin

    admin.site.register(SystemA)
    admin.site.register(SystemB)
```

3.) And this is my views.py definition:

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from acc.models import SystemA, SystemB
    from django.template import Context, loader
    from itertools import chain
    from operator import attrgetter

    def index(request):
      a_list = SystemA.objects.all().order_by('-date')
      b_list = SystemB.objects.all().order_by('-date')
      result_list = sorted(
        chain(a_list, b_list),
        key=attrgetter('date'))
      t = loader.get_template('index.html')
      #c = Context({'result_list': result_list,})
      c = Context({'a_list': a_list,'b_list': b_list,})
      return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

4.) Finally, the template presenting the static HTML page (index.html) is defined as:

```
    {% if a_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for a in a_list %}
    <li>{{a.date}} | {{a.author}} | {{a.system}} | {{a.description}} | {{a.status}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}

    {% if b_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for b in b_list %}
    <li>{{b.date}} | {{b.author}} | {{b.system}} | {{b.description}} | {{b.status}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

The code is working and I've entered some data from the admin interface. The result:

```
April 18, 2013 | owta | System A | All jobs went bananas! | FAILED
April 17, 2013 | rash | System A | All Well | OK

April 18, 2013 | owta | System B | All jobs went bananas! | FAILED
April 17, 2013 | rash | System B | All well | OK
```

My aim is to get a result sorted on date, independently from the models (SystemA/SystemB) in below sort order:

```
April 17, 2013 | rash | System A | All Well | OK
April 17, 2013 | rash | System B | All well | OK
April 18, 2013 | owta | System A | All jobs went bananas! | FAILED
April 18, 2013 | owta | System B | All jobs went bananas! | FAILED
```

I've spent a haft week trying to sort this out without success, and I'm a noob into Django. Some help
would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You may want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313137/using-django-how-can-i-combine-two-queries-from-separate-models-into-one-query

Comment: Why aren't you using result list in the template?

Comment: Any reason you have to use 2 tables for the different systems? why not a single model with a choice field to say what kind of system it is

Comment: Jeff: Thanks. But using result_list just shows a blank page. That's why I've uncommented it.

Comment: Thomas: Thanks. I was into a one-model solution before, but somehow felt that I had to have different classes/models for my systems in order to fetch data nicely into a static page sorted on date from each system. Would be greatful if you could give me a sample code or share a link demonstrating this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I was into a one-model solution before, but somehow felt that I had to have different classes/models for my systems in order to fetch data nicely into a static page sorted on date from each system"

Well rash, this is how you would do it with one model. Remember, always try to reduce duplication in your system.

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    author  = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.author)

class System(models.Model):
    SYSTEM_CHOICES = (('A','System A'),('B','System B'))
    author      = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    date        = models.DateField()
    system      = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SYSTEM_CHOICES) # see [1]
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    status      = models.CharField(max_length=6)
```

#### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

class SystemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['system'] # See [2]

admin.site.register(System, SystemAdmin)
```

#### urls.py

```
url(r'^/system/(?P<system>A|B)/list/$', views.SystemListView.as_view(), name='system-list' )
```

#### views.py

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .models import System

class SystemListView(ListView):
    model = System
    context_object_name = "Systems"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(SystemListView, self) \
          .filter(system = self.kwargs['system']) \
          .order_by(self.request.GET.get('sort') or '-date')
```

#### {template_folder}/yourapp/system/list.html

```
<h1> System {{ system }}{# See [3] #} </h1>
<ul>
{% for sys in Systems %}
  <li>{{sys.date}} | {{sys.author}} | {{sys.description}} | {{sys.status}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

#### Appendix

```
[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#choices
[2] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter
[3] https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L99
```

Comment: Thanks a million, Thomas! This code set looks brilliant, although I'll have to grasp a few things from your appendix in order to understand a few things. I'm eager to get to work tomorrow to try this out! Regards.

Comment: Hey, if this worked out for you, would you consider marking the answer as correct?

Comment: No problems, @rash. I'm glad to help